# disable two buttons after clicking another button

Tags: php, html, button, disable

so i need to be able to disable two buttons (approve and return button) once i successfully click the close button. can anyone help me? the first part of the code are the buttons i need to disable.

```
<div class="text-center ">
    <button class="btn m-1 align-items-center btn-success text-center " type="submit" id="approve_button" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#approveModal">Approve</button>   
    <button class="btn btn-secondary m-1 align-items-center text-center" type="submit" id="return_button" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#returnModal">Return</button>       
    </div>


<div>
<button class="btn btn-danger m-5 align-items-center text-center"  id="reject_button" name="reject_button" data-toggle="modal"data-target="#rejectModal" >Close Task</button>
</div>
<?php 
if (isset($_POST["reject-btn"])){ 
    
    $rejectt = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $_POST["rejectt"]);
    $sql = "UPDATE task SET task_status='closed'  WHERE id_task='$rejectt' ";
    $result_rej = mysqli_query($con, $sql);
    if ($result_rej) {
        $_SESSION['success'] = "Task closed";
        $_SESSION['text'] = "Task has been closed successfully";
        $_SESSION['icon'] = "success";
   
    } else {
        $_SESSION['success'] = "Error";
        $_SESSION['text'] = "Unknown error, please try again";
        $_SESSION['icon'] = "error";
    }

 }
?>
   <?php
    if (isset($_SESSION['success']) && $_SESSION['success'] != '') {
    ?>
        <script>
            swal({
                title: "<?php echo $_SESSION['success']; ?>",
                text: "<?php echo $_SESSION['text']; ?>",
                icon: "<?php echo $_SESSION['icon']; ?>",
                button: "OK";
                
            });
        </script>
    <?php
        unset($_SESSION['success']);
    }
    ?>
```

Comment: Rearrange the script so that showing/echoing those buttons is dependent on the current status value from your database.

Comment: do i put the script first before the buttons?

Comment: Do you want to disable the buttons permanently, or just while the page is posting back from the other click?

Comment: @ADyson permanently

Comment: Ok so none of the JavaScript-based solutions below will work then, because the buttons will be reset when you refresh the page or submit the form

Comment: You should move the `if (isset($_POST["reject-btn"])){ ` section first in your script so that it updates the status in the DB before anything else when the form is submitted. The, as I said, write a query to check the current status (which will run regardless of whether the Close button has just been clicked or not), and then write an `if` statement to check that status, and put the buttons you want to control inside that `if`.

Answer (score 1):

You can add disabled attribute to buttons when clicked #reject_button by using jQuery

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("#reject_button").click(function(){
     $("#approve_button, #return_button").attr("disabled","true");
  });
});
```

Comment: where do you reckon i put this part in? at the last php?

Comment: @Eya yes put it after php inside <script> tag

Comment: hi do you know a way to have the button disabled permanently?

Comment: Do you need them disabled even after refreshing the page ?

Comment: Yes that's what i need

Answer (score 0):

You can add a disabled attribute to buttons when clicked #reject_button by using normal javascript

```js
document.querySelector(document).ready(function(){
  document.querySelector("#reject_button").click(function(){
     document.querySelector("#approve_button, #return_button").attr("disabled","true");
  });
});
```

Comment: where do you reckon i put this part in? at the last php?

Comment: add that inside a `<script></script>` at the end of your php script, just before the `?>` ending php tag

Comment: hi do you know a way to have the button disabled permanently?

Comment: add this `disabled="true"` to the button like `<button disabled="true"></button>`

Answer (score 0):

You can do this using a simple JS event handler. The provided example is one way. If you need to enable them again in the future, you'll need a separate event handler to remove the disabled attribute.

```
<script>
//you can replace querySelector with getElementById, but I prefer the flexibility of query selector
  document.querySelector('#reject_button').addEventListener('onclick', () => {
    document.querySelector('#approve_button').setAttribute('disabled',"");
    document.querySelector('#return_button').setAttribute('disabled',"");
  });
</script>
```

Comment: where do you reckon i put this part in? at the last php?

Comment: hi do you know a way to have the button disabled permanently?

Comment: You would put the script tag at the bottom of the page before the closing ```</body>``` tag. Disabled permanently is a relative term. If you mean so that it never works, the best bet is to just remove the HTML. You asked about disabling it on a button click. That happens after page load, so JS is your best bet. If you want the disable to be triggered during page load as a result of some PHP, and not by button click, then you would need to write some PHP to add the disabled attribute by condition, or have the rendering of the button be conditional. You should probably clarify your question.

Answer (score 0):

If you need them disabled even after page refresh then you can use this.
But most convenient way is you should try to save the button status in database.

```
<div class="text-center ">

    <?php if(isset($_SESSION['disable-buttons']) ){
                if($_SESSION['disable-buttons'] == true){

                    $disabled = "disabled";

                }else{

                $disabled = "";
                
                } 
        }

     ?>

    <button class="btn m-1 align-items-center btn-success text-center " type="submit" id="approve_button" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#approveModal" <?php echo $disabled ?> >Approve</button>   
    <button class="btn btn-secondary m-1 align-items-center text-center" type="submit" id="return_button" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#returnModal" <?php echo $disabled ?> >Return</button>       
    </div>


<div>
<button class="btn btn-danger m-5 align-items-center text-center"  id="reject_button" name="reject_button" data-toggle="modal"data-target="#rejectModal" >Close Task</button>
</div>
<?php 
if (isset($_POST["reject_button"])){ 

    $_SESSION['disable-buttons'] = true; 
    
    $rejectt = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $_POST["rejectt"]);
    $sql = "UPDATE task SET task_status='closed'  WHERE id_task='$rejectt' ";
    $result_rej = mysqli_query($con, $sql);
    if ($result_rej) {
        $_SESSION['success'] = "Task closed";
        $_SESSION['text'] = "Task has been closed successfully";
        $_SESSION['icon'] = "success";
   
    } else {
        $_SESSION['success'] = "Error";
        $_SESSION['text'] = "Unknown error, please try again";
        $_SESSION['icon'] = "error";
    }

 }
?>
   <?php
    if (isset($_SESSION['success']) && $_SESSION['success'] != '') {
    ?>
        <script>
            swal({
                title: "<?php echo $_SESSION['success']; ?>",
                text: "<?php echo $_SESSION['text']; ?>",
                icon: "<?php echo $_SESSION['icon']; ?>",
                button: "OK";
                
            });
        </script>
    <?php
        unset($_SESSION['success']);
    }
    ?>
```

Comment: hi! i tried doing this and it worked! but even when i haven't clicked the reject button, the other buttons become disabled already

Comment: May be it happens because you have clicked "reject" button once after that the session variable gets set. 
You've told in previous comment that you want buttons to be disabled even after refresh the page so this is the way to do it. If this is not what you are looking for then you must explain your question much more after that I can try to help you out.